# Why my action method not triggered when I make post call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I use MVC ASP.

Here is javascript object that I sent to action method:

```
  var layerProp = {VectorLayerId:5, FieldName: "someText", FieldType:"someText", FieldValue: "someText", Required:false }
```

and here is my ajax function:

```
function saveProperty(layerProp, callback, error) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/Mobile/LayerProperty/SaveProperty',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { layerProp: layerProp },
        success: callback,
        error: error
    });
}
```

Here is my action type in controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveProperty(GeomindMobile.Core.Data.VectorLayers_Fields layerProp)
    {
        try
        {
            var q = _repository.SaveProperty(layerProp);
            return Json(new { Result = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "Bad", ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Here is my entity that type defenition:

```
public partial class VectorLayers_Fields
{
    public VectorLayers_Fields()
    {
        this.VectorLayer_FieldsValue = new HashSet<VectorLayer_FieldsValue>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VectorLayerId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VectorLayer_FieldsValue> VectorLayer_FieldsValue { get; set; }
}
```

Any  idea why I get this error when I post my data to the controller:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**UPDATE:**

Here is massege about error that I get in fiddler:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: layerProp.]
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() +707
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +333
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +110
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +46
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext) +230
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +45
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +223
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +263
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +504
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +361
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +143
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +744
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +164
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +164
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +532
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +164
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +416
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +164
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +309
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1028
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the exception stack trace is server side?

Have you tried placing a break-point in the action method to see if it hits?

Comment: What is the description of 500?

Comment: @MartinBlore yes I tryed it dosen't reach ti the action method

Comment: You need to tell us what the exception message is at least. We can't help until then. 500 could indicate a massive range of problems with the web server or your web project.

Comment: @MartinBlore please see update.

Comment: Remove the `contentType` option and it will work fine  (otherwise you must stringify the data using `JSON.stringify()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS AJAX call, try changing the data property from:

```
data: { layerProp: layerProp },
```

To:

```
data: JSON.stringify(layerProp),
```

The mistake you're making is that the data you are providing is an object with the property "layerProp". So if we write that as a C# class, you'll get this:

```
class Whatever
{
    public SomeType LayerProp { get; set; }
}
```

The type you're expecting on your controller is the object with all your values on like FieldName, FieldType etc. So in JSON format, the start of your JSON object (the first {), should contain these properties. Such as:

```
data: { 'Id': 10, FieldName: 'Hello', FieldType: 'World'....
```

The JSON.stringify is a helper function in all browser that safely converts values/symbols inside JS objects to the correct JSON formats. For example, it will take a JS Date object and convert it to a valid date/time string with timezone information. It's just easier/safer to use this when trying to create JSON strings out of a JS object. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  it's works.Can you pleas give brief explanation?

Comment: @Michael Updated the answer :)